# dotnet adds package and reference but it does not appear in build

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've added package to the F# project on MacOS:

```
dotnet add news.fsproj package TweetinviAPI
```

Its output seems to be ok:

```
  Writing /var/folders/lb/_pl810795rn9jf76nn_5z1dr0000gn/T/tmpqfN6SC.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'TweetinviAPI' into project 'news.fsproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for /Users/alex/Projects/news/news.fsproj...
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fsharp.core/index.json
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fsharp.core/index.json 685ms
warn : Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
info : Package 'TweetinviAPI' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'news.fsproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'TweetinviAPI' version '8.0.0.2' updated in file '/Users/alex/Projects/news/news.fsproj'.
```

The fsproj contains reference which also seems ok.

But `dotnet build` does not really add the package to the bin folder and if any code referencing the library fails with undefined identifier.

.NET version is 2.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `dotnet remove` and add it again with the version like this:

`dotnet add package TweetinviAPI --version 2.1.0`

As you can see in your output the version it adds if you don't specify the version is 8.0.0.2. This is a completely different package that contains all the sources. Not sure why this happens because if you open it on the NuGet website this version is not visible.